# How to implement crud functionality between SP 2010 online (365) and MS CRM Dynamics Online 2011

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, dynamics-crm

I would like to create some CRUD (get, add, edit, remove) functionality in my SP 2010 Online (office 365) environment to control items in MS CRM Dynamics Online 2011.

This is the list (Service Requests) where I would like to do my CRUD functionality on:

[image]

Please give me some more information where to start?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the SharePoint side, but in terms of communicating with CRM there are REST and SOAP web services you can use.

I suggest starting on the MSDN, it contains examples and explanations of how to perform CRUD operations.

[Write Applications and Server Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334357.aspx)